# Push doesn't work in map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I try to add new property checking whether a sibling array is empty but not able to achieve what I want with push.

https://jsbin.com/zutiboyaji/edit?html,js,console,output

```
let x = [{
    "name": [{
        "first": "m",
        "last": "jordan"
    }],
    "extraObj": [{
        "something": "bla bla bla"
    }]
}]

const result = x.map(obj => {
  if(obj.extraObj.length > 1){
    obj.name.extraObj.push({"whatever":"whatever"})
  }

  return obj
})

console.log(result)
```

What's wrong with my loop above?

Comment: `name` is undefined - try `obj.extraObj.push`

Comment: @JaromandaX edited the question.

Comment: I don't understand the logic ... now `obj.name.extraObj` doesn't exist, so same problem - where are you trying to add "whatever", and why only if there are 2 or more `extraObj`? can you show your expected result please

Comment: What is your expected output? @AlanJenshen

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 1):

Your if condition is failing because you are checking `length>1` you should use `length >=1`. and there is no `name` object. Use `obj.extraObj.push`

```js
let x = [{
    "name": [{
        "first": "m",
        "last": "jordan"
    }],
    "extraObj": [{
        "something": "bla bla bla"
    }]
}]

const result = x.map(obj => {
  if(obj.extraObj.length >= 1){
    obj.extraObj.push({"whatever":"whatever"})
  }
  
  return obj
})

console.log(result)
```